# How to set imenu to a list of errors in compilation mode

Tags: compilation-mode, imenu

I would like to use `helm-imenu` to see and navigate on a list of errors/warnings in compilation buffer.  How can I do that? E.g., by setting `imenu-generic-expression` to some value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be better off setting `imenu-create-index-function` I think, so instead of repeating the regexps, you can directly use the matching already performed by `compile.el`.  The necessary function would logically fit into `compile.el`, so you may want to submit it for inclusion into Emacs when you're done.